# disable softkeypad is popping up automatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

softkeypad is poping up automatically when i press a button...i have tried following code to stop poping up the softkeypad but in vain...following is the code that i have tried :

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Airport.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

even in **manifest** file i have done the following:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

but surprisingly i haven't used any edittext...but also this softkeypad is poping up....can anyone plz answer this....its an emergency...thank u in advanced

Comment: is there any control where ur making focus?

Comment: will you please post your button click method..

Comment: just remove android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" this line from manifest.

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {

if (v.getId() == R.id.air_pick) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Airport.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);       ....air_pick is the button....and Airport is another class where i want to call from Main class...This Airport class only contains buttons and nothing at all....this code is from Main.java class....please anyone can solve this...?? thanks everyone who have tried to help me..

Comment: Try this in your manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" ...also didn't work...can anyone plz...its being urgent...i have tried everything

Comment: InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0):

try this its intresting to hide the softkeypad

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    //check if no view has focus:
    View v=this.getCurrentFocus();
    if(v==null)
        return;

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: have you reach the goal

Comment: this also didn't work...its being a real problem...is there any other way...??

Comment: post your onclick method,i'll  help

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
 
  if (v.getId() == R.id.air_pick) {
  Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Airport.class);
    startActivity(i);........in this code air_pick is the button to be clicked which is in Main.java class...after clicking it focus should be transfered to Airport.class....this Airport.java contains only 4 buttons and nothing else....and when air_pick button is pressed,Airport.java is called and meanwhile softkeypad pops up...

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);  try this and let me inform

Comment: try this link it will help u dude             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1